# Copy the value of integer from one variable to another by using only 1 character pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This was one of the question i got in an interview , he had asked me if i could copy the value of 1 integer variable (say i = 100) to another variable j by using only character pointer.

```
main()
{        
    int i = 100;
    char *p;
    int j = 0;
   /*Write code here to copy the value of i into j  by using only the                        
   character pointer p*/
}
```

Comment: Unclear specification...  Obviously impossible if you are only allowed to create one rvalue of `char *` type; and simple if you are allowed multiple such values

Comment: Thank you for sharing your interview question. But you appear to be on the wrong website. Looks like you were looking for howwasmyinterview.com, but you ended up on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: That link isnt opening buddy

Comment: @M.M.. what is unclear in this specification?

Comment: In the title you say "using only 1 character pointer" then in the question you say "using only character pointer", not specifying an amount.  Then you did not say exactly what you mean by whichever of those it is.

Comment: can this character pointer be unsigned?

Answer (score 2):

Well, say we have:

```
int i = 100;
int j;
char *ptr;
```

Then you could write:

```
for (ptr = (char *)&i; ptr != (char *)(&i + 1); ++ptr)
    ((char *)&j)[ptr - (char *)&i] = *ptr;
```

Obviously there are a lot of pointer *values* here but it is impossible to do your task without using many of those.

Comment: @M.M..Thanks for that answer. But is there anyway we could use memcpy?

Comment: What?/   memcpy takes TWO pointers as arguments and so is ruled out by, well, your rules.

Comment: @stackoverflow well, you could write `memcpy(&j, &i, sizeof j);` and not use any char pointer at all.  This is what I mean by your specification being unclear.

Comment: I fear this is the "answer": `memcpy((&p)+1, (char*)(&p)-sizeof(int), sizeof(int));`. Which is u.b. of course.